# How can I use LastRow on a range function?

Tags: vba, excel

So I want to copy values from a certain range of cells from worksheet 1-workbook A to worksheet 1- workbook B .

I want to copy everything from the source worksheet: more specifically, every cell that has a value on it.

On the destination worksheet, there are specified cells for the values on source worksheet.

this is my code so far (it's bad, but i'm a noob at VBA!) :

```
Sub CopyRangeofCells()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook



Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\test\template.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\test\finalfile.xlsx")


x.Sheets("RDBMergeSheet").Range("A1").Copy


y.Sheets("CW Fast").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

'Close x:
x.Close

End Sub
```

On my range, I want to do something like Range("A1:LastRow") or anything of the sort. How do I do it? Can I create a lastrow variable and then do ("A1:mylastrowvariable") ??

Hope you can help! VBA is so confusing to me, give me Java all day long! :P

Comment: Use the last cell on sheet then `.end(xlUp).row`

Comment: Start by watching this video: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it step-by-step:

```
Sub CopyRangeofCells()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\test\template.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\test\finalfile.xlsx")

With x.Sheets("RDBMergeSheet")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in column "A"

    .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Copy
End With

y.Sheets("CW Fast").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Close x:
x.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: sounds good but i'm getting a "subscript out-of-range" error and it highlights this line on the debugger :

y.Sheets("CW Fast").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

Comment: still same error on the paste line. How can it get out-of-range? Only two things I can think of that might conflict with this is the fact I have filters on that column, and data validation. Can this be an explanation to this error?

Comment: @MiguelSáLemos Filters ? on which of the worksheets ? also, are you sure your `"CW Fast")` is spelled exactly like this on `y` workbook ?

Comment: on the destination worksheet, the headers have filters. Yes, the worksheet is named "CW Fast"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Sub CopyRangeofCells()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim LastRow as Long
Dim LastRowToCopy as Long

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\test\template.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\test\finalfile.xlsx")

LastRowToCopy = x.Sheets("RDBMergeSheet").Cells(x.Sheets("RDBMergeSheet").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
x.Sheets("RDBMergeSheet").Range("A1:A" & LastRowToCopy).Copy
'copy from A1 to lastrow
LastRow = y.Sheets("CW Fast").Cells(y.Sheets("CW Fast").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'find the last row 
y.Sheets("CW Fast").Range("A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'paste on the lastrow of destination + 1 (so next empty row)
x.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't that finding the last row on my destination target instead of my source? i'm so confused ._.

Comment: I've updated my answer to find the last row of your range to copy and then find the last row on your destination to paste...

Comment: damn, it looks perfect, but it gives me subscript out-of-range error on finding the last row on destination :( i'll keep going by trial and error to see why it's happening, thanks!

Comment: maybe if you just want to paste onto A1 on your destination, you don't have to include the lastrow? but something else must be at play here for you to get a subscript out of range, maybe double check the sheet name of your destination?